# Dynamic SQL Command push into Temp table

Tags: t-sql, temp

I need to push the results from this code below into a undefined TEMP table. Temp table must be undefined because I wont know the column names of the result set .

```
declare @sql varchar(4000)
set @sql ='Select * from #Test'

exec (@sql)
```

--Need to insert the final result set into #TempTableName because I need to use it in code lower down in my Stored Procedure.

Comment: Boils down to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure "How to SELECT * INTO [temp table] FROM [stored procedure]").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.............

Needed to use a Global Temp table and that did it for me.

```
declare @sql varchar(4000)
set @sql ='Select * INTO ##TempTableName from #Test'

exec (@sql) 

Select * from ##TempTableName
```

The ## is for a global temp table and that worked for me.